# facing issue while installing composer require asm/php-ansible with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, composer-php

I am executing below command

```
composer require asm/php-ansible
```

I am getting below out put

```
 - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.4.8, v4.1.0].
- Can only install one of: symfony/process[v3.4.9, v4.1.0].
- Installation request for symfony/process (locked at v4.1.0) -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v4.1.0].
```

I have checked my symfony/process version. It shows me v4.1.0.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that **asm/php-ansible** has old versions of **symfony/process** defined in it's dependencies: **"~2.6|~3.0"**

Please refer here:
https://github.com/maschmann/php-ansible/blob/master/composer.json#L16

You have two options now:

1) Create an issue (from here: https://github.com/maschmann/php-ansible/issues), raising the questing if it's possible that they update their **symfony/process** dependency to accept versions **~4.0** and wait for them to resolve it.

or

2) Downgrade the package which depends on **symfony/process**. I guess that's not a very good option. But if you decide to go that road, you should first check which package depends on this. You can do this via this command:

```
composer depends symfony/process
```

My guess is that it's the laravel/framework in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But how could i overcome on this issue?

Comment: I've updated my answer, giving you two options. Hope one of them helps you.